# ¿Cómo comparar valores en un array multidimensional en php?

Tags: php, php7

Hola buenas estoy recorriendo un array multidimensional y lo que necesito es comparar las fechas que existen y si se repiten necesito dejar solo una en el array y coger el enlace que se encuentre dentro de la que se repitió y añadírselo a la que dejo y eliminarlo una vez que obtuve su enlace. El enlace se encuentra dentro del array eventos que a su vez se encuentra dentro el array.
Lo que no logro ver es como se que valor pertenece al primer array y cual al segundo y así viceversa para poder comparar una fecha con otra y así sucesivamente, lo que he hecho hasta ahora es lo sgt:

```
    $event_js = array(
    array(
        'fecha' => '12/02/2021', 
        'eventos' => array('enlace' => '<a href="#">evento1</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '23/03/2021', 
        'eventos' => array('enlace' => '<a href="#">evento2</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '23/03/2021', 
        'eventos'=> array('enlace'=>'<a href="#">evento3</a>')
    )
);

$i =0;
foreach( $event_js as $key=>$event){
    $fecha = $event['fecha'];

    /*if(in_array($fecha, $event_js[$key])){
        var_dump($fecha);
    }*/
       var_dump( $fecha);

       if($event_js[$i]['fecha'] == $fecha ){
           echo "existe";
           $i++;
       }
    foreach( $event as $colum){
        //var_dump($colum);
    }
}
```

Si alguien me ayuda a verlo más claro no tengo mucha experiencia con array multidimensionales y me cuesta ver lo que necesito hacer. Gracias

ejemplo de como necesito que se quede el array final:

```
$event_js = array(
    array(
        'fecha' => '12/02/2021', 
        'eventos' => array('enlace' => '<a href="#">evento1</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '23/03/2021', 
        'eventos' => array(
            'enlace' => '<a href="#">evento2</a>',
            'enlace'=>'<a href="#">evento3</a>')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seguro que hay alguna manera un poco más sencilla de hacerlo porque yo mismo lo he hecho sin necesidad de utilizar la función *array_values* ni tener que reasignar la nueva longitud del array, pero ahora mismo no recuerdo como lo hice. Probablemente alguien pueda mejorar el código.

De todas formas, lo que he hecho es directamente lo que necesitas (sin necesidad de ninguna idea adicional, quiero decir).

Échale un vistazo a ver que te parece:

```
$event_js = array(
    array(
        'fecha' => '12/02/2021', 
        'eventos' => array('<a href="#">evento1</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '23/03/2021', 
        'eventos' => array('<a href="#">evento2</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '23/03/2021', 
        'eventos'=> array('<a href="#">evento3</a>')
    ),
    array(
        'fecha' => '25/03/2021', 
        'eventos'=> array('<a href="#">evento4</a>')
    )
);

$n = count($event_js);

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
    $fecha = $event_js[$i]['fecha'];
    for($j=$i+1;$j<$n;$j++){
        if($event_js[$j]['fecha'] == $fecha){
            $evento = $event_js[$j]['eventos'][0];
            $event_js[$i]['eventos'][] = $evento;
            unset($event_js[$j]);
            $event_js = array_values($event_js);
            $n = count($event_js);
            break;
        }
    }
}


print_r($event_js);
```

Nota: es posible que haya algún caso que no haya podido tener en cuenta. Lo he creado a pelo y sin mucho tiempo para mirar. Asegurate y mira todos los posibles casos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de todo corazón, me funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si la respuesta solucionó el problema de tu pregunta considera marcarla como Correcta y darle un voto positivo. La mejor manera de agradecerlo es esa ^^

Comment: ¿como puedo votar también este respuesta?

Comment: He estado mirando y haciéndolo con ese tipo de for da una inconsistencia un elemento del array se muestra como null, se podría hacer con el foreach? algún ejemplo por favor?

Comment: @Caocar, hacerlo con foreach sería en un principio practicamente igual. De todas formas, qué error te da? puedes copiarlo y ponerlo aquí?